# Bluej null pointer exception

Tags: java, bluej

I'm trying to put a simple cardgame together, and I ran into a NullPointerException, the program compiles though if I run it and run the method `setSuit`, I get this error message:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
  at Cards.setCard(Cards.java:18)
  at Cards.<init>(Cards.java:11)
```

I've posted the code below and marked the highlighted area:

```
public class Cards {
    private String HEARTS = "Hearts";
    private String CLUBS = "Clubs";
    private String DIAMONDS = "Diamonds";
    private String SPADES = "Spades";
    private int number;
    private String suit;
    public Cards(String newCard, int newNumber1) {
        setCard(newCard);
        setNumber(newNumber1);
    }

    public void setCard(String newSuit) {
        if((suit != null) && // this part get's highlighted 
          (suit.equalsIgnoreCase(HEARTS)) ||
          (suit.equalsIgnoreCase(DIAMONDS)) ||
          (suit.equalsIgnoreCase(CLUBS))    ||
          (suit.equalsIgnoreCase(SPADES))) {
            suit = newSuit;
        } else {
            suit = "Unknown Suit";
            System.out.print("Invalid");
        }

    }
    public int getNumber() {
         return number;
    }

    public String getSuit() {
         return suit;
    }

    public void setNumber(int newNumber) {
         number = newNumber;
         if(newNumber >0 && newNumber <=10) {
              number = newNumber;
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have never done that before, how?

Comment: Note the stack trace: `(Cards.java:18)`, the `Cards.java` is the file with the exception, and the `18` is the line number it occurs on.

Comment: Well if you google, "bluej debugging tutorial", there a many, many links.

Comment: Thank you, i'l look into it.

Comment: Doesn't change the fact that i don't know what this nul pointer exception is :p

Comment: You are trying to reference an object that is null.  It was not initialized somewhere.

Comment: not directly related to your question, but you may want to check the logic in the `setNumber` method.

Comment: Your problem is with `setCard()`. You are checking if suit is not null, but you are trying to set a newSuit, so you should check if that is not null and one of the known suits. It's not clear why BlueJ complains on that particular line of code, because, while illogical, it does not appear incorrect.

Comment: I found the error, everything works now, thank you all! :) and yes, i repeated number = newnumber once to many, ty for pointing that out

Answer (score 2):

It's an order of operations issue.  Try this instead:

```
if ((suit != null) && (suit.equalsIgnoreCase(HEARTS) || suit.equalsIgnoreCase(DIAMONDS) || suit.equalsIgnoreCase(CLUBS) || suit.equalsIgnoreCase(SPADES)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this, but I think setCard should be:

```
public void setCard(String newSuit)
    {
    if((newSuit != null) && //this part get's highlighted 
    (newSuit.equalsIgnoreCase(HEARTS)) ||
    (newSuit.equalsIgnoreCase(DIAMONDS)) ||
    (newSuit.equalsIgnoreCase(CLUBS))    ||
    (newSuit.equalsIgnoreCase(SPADES)))
    {
        suit = newSuit;
    }
    else 
    {
        suit = "Unknown Suit";
        System.out.print("Invalid");
    }
}
```

Comment: Someone else has suggested an improved coding style should be improved, but my goal was to make your code work not just change its style.

Comment: I suspect that your code will still not work; if that is the case, please check my suggested change to `setCard()`

Comment: My code works now, i got rid of the != null param, and had indeed forgotten to declare suit, however it did take some more tinkering like you said